# Adding an XCode breakpoint for logging NSData returned for NSRequest

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

I found breakpoint to be very convenient for getting rid of all NSLog statements trough all my code. This time I am looking for a way to print the html response coming from an NSRequest in a breakpoint.

Assuming returnData is the variable returned from my NSRequest, I have tried to add a breakpoint with a debugger command like this:

> po (@"%@", returnData)

but it's giving me the whole HEX response

I then tried with this

> po ([[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])

but I am getting an error: **use of undeclared identifier 'NSUTF8StringEncoding'**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NSUTF8StringEncoding is an NSUInteger, in NSString.h you can see the value is 4, so you could do this

```
po [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:4]
```

Answer (score -1):

NSUTF8StringEncoding is enum declared in NSString.h which is declared in foundation framework.
did you double check that foundation framework is imported in project ?
if yes, then try to import NSString.h and recompile.

On the other hand I print nsdata like this

```
       NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

       NSLog(@"Response:%@",responseString);
```

Comment: Probably because the original question specifically asked how to perform the task using po in the debugger.